# Using the right Memory speeds

Tags: memory

I am building up a new system and the intel mother board I am using specs DDR3 1333 memory, is there a problem with using DDR3 1600?

Comment: Long story short: YES. DDR3 memory is backwards compatible.

If your motherboard doesn't support the higher speed, it will down-clock the RAM to 1333 MHz.

Answer (score 0):

If the motherboard supports 1600, then no problem.

If it does not support 1600 then it may cause the system to not power up, or at the minimum the bios will clock it back to 1333 speeds.